# Выделение текста в форме

Tags: html, javascript

Есть ссылка. Я хочу, что бы она была в форме (поле), и при нажатии на поле сразу все выделялось. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input onfocus="javascript:this.select()">
```

Comment: javascript? 100 лет уже не видел такой формат. Все браузеры понимают просто onfocus="this.select()"

Comment: и чо?&nbsp;

Comment: Если уж придираться к таким вещам, то стоит напомнить, что инлайновые скрипты вообще не комильфо. Нужно вешать обработчик через addEventListener и attachEvent.

Comment: @sorx00 тут вы правы. Но тут случай-то совсем другой. Да и потом, о каких эвентах мы можем говорить, если люди просто за правильные ответы минусы ставят? Школьники чтоль негодуют...